# Binary floating point numbers using two integers?

Tags: floating-point, binary

Today i learned a bit about how floating point numbers are expressed binary.
Well, i can see why the IEE-754 technical standard is smart for storing a huge range of numbers using relatively few bits. Also i see why it's useful to sometimes to express each symbol as four 4-bits(Like you can do i Cobol, right?), when you want very precise numbers.

Anyways, my question is, isn't it more convenient to "just" store floating point numbers as two integers? For example, you could express the number before the comma as a 34 bit integer and the number after the comma as a 30 bit integer. Then'd you be able to write any number in the range of +-8,5 billion with approximately 9 decimals, right?

It's still a relatively small range of numbers compared to double precision floating points, but as far as i can see it's better than the Cobol way?

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be describing binary fixed-point numbers, which are often used but less convenient than floating-point since you have to manually juggle the precision and stay clear of overflow. I must confess not to know how COBOL stores number but I suspect it uses decimal fixed-point, which is inefficient for general computation but required for precise calculation of decimal fractions (i.e. rounding tends to get rather strict when money is involved).

Comment: You're probably right. As i said, i've just learned about floating point numbers today, and the Cobol way and the IEEE-754 are the only ones i've been introduced to so far.
I'm still abit curious as to why fixed decimal floating-point is worse than the cobal way?

Comment: Imagine you were writing a calculator application. How would you assign the bits for your fixed-point numbers used for the arithmetic? What would the largest and smallest numbers required be?

Comment: I don't really understand your point, maybe you can clarify it with an example? Please bare with me :/

Comment: I took a quick peek at COBOL (hopefully not long enough to be contaminated) and it seems to primarily use fixed-point BCD numbers. Such a format is wasteful for storage and inefficient in calculations, but very fast to input or print as decimal numbers for human consumption

Comment: My point is that on desk calculator you may desire to compute both the size of an atom as well as the size of the universe, and that's a huge range to cover with a fixed number of integer and fractional digits. Thankfully the vast majority of the time you only really care about the ten or so largest decimals, so a floating-point scheme can get by with only saving the most-significant digits (the mantissa) and about large the number is (the exponent)

Comment: COBOL has several formats for storing numeric values.  Integers can be stored as text (very wasteful), as BCD (slightly wasteful), or as pure binary.  Non-integers are typically stored as decimal fixed-point.

Comment: Thank you doynax and dan04!
I see your point donax if you compare floating points to fixed point numbers in general, but the cobol way(BCD?), is, as far as i can work out, also fixed point, and in that case it has the same disadventage as my proposed way? So why did the cobol engineers use such a "wasteful" type of real numbers, when they could just as easily have done something much simpler? Just because it was faster to display?
If i completely misunderstood something, then please don't bother replying anymore. I should probably have done a bit more research before i asked the question.

Comment: Back in the 50s when COBOL was designed the primary means of input and output was through punch-cards. That means that you were requiring users (humans or very simple machines) to read and write binary numbers. Now, would you as the data clerk have preferred the COBOL (BCD) way or the binary way?

Comment: Well that explains it :)
And thank you btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The advantages of floating-point are that:

1. They allow a huge range of numbers. A 32-bit float has far more range than a 32.32 (64-bit total) fixed-point number such as you suggest.
2. They have consistent precision -- a 32-bit float is precise to at least one part in 8 million across almost all of its range (it loses precision when extremely close to zero).
3. They have special values for infinity (to handle overflow) and Not A Number (to handle undefined calculations such as zero divided by zero).

In contrast, fixed-point numbers have quite limited range, are only precise over a limited range, and lack special values for infinity and Not A Number. Consider this calculation to calculate the length of a vector:

```
return sqrt(vec.x * vec.x + vec.y * vec.y);
```

This calculation can overflow or underflow even if the final result fits because the argument to sqrt will have an exponent about twice as large as the final result. This problem usually doesn't matter when using float or double because their range is so huge, but with a fixed-point format this problem is easy to hit. Assuming a 32.32 fixed-point format it is difficult to calculate the length of a vector that is as short as 70,000 units.

Worse yet, there is no convenient way to indicate that the calculation has overflowed.

Also, fixed-point math does not have hardware support which makes it less efficient for some operations.

That said, fixed-point math absolutely does make sense in some specific cases. It is commonly used for storing time, or world coordinates, where the consistent precision (instead of consistent relative precision) is a benefit. However for generic calculations fixed-point math is cumbersome and error prone.

Comment: Decimal fixed-point math would be superior to *decimal* floating-point math (as exemplified by the `Decimal` type in .NET) in almost every way; for some purposes it would be best to store a binary count of some power-of-ten unit (e.g. billionths), while for others wit would be better to store a whole number plus a number of billionths.

Comment: Binary floating-point math is provably more 'efficient' than base-ten. The 'wobble' (variance in precision depending on the leading digit) is five times worse for base-ten. Base-ten floating-point would also waste bits because a 31-bit number (ignoring the sign bit) can store 2.1 billion but base-ten would have to cap it at 1.0 billion.

Decimal allows for easier and more intuitive conversions to human readable base-10. Base-10 is inferior to base-2 in most other ways.

Fixed-point is inferior in many other ways.

Base-10 makes sense in certain domain specific areas such as finance.

Comment: Decimal floating-point is pretty horrid.  Decimal *fixed*-point math, however, would seem appropriate in cases where the things to be represented are power-of-ten fractions of a unit.  Depending upon the mix of operations to be performed, storing a 128-bit fixed-decimal number using 32 bits for each group of 9 digits may be allow some operations to be performed more efficiently than storing as it as a straight binary number.

Comment: There would be significant performance cost, especially for arbitrary multiplication and division, especially for 32-bit processes. And overflow would always be a greater risk than with floating-point, but yes, there are advantages to fixed-point for some scenarios.

Comment: If one stored a straight binary number of quintillions, multiplication and division would require dividing by a power of ten that exceeded 2^32.  Splitting at least the fractional part of the number into chunks that represent one, two, or four billion precisely would simplify such operations.  In any case, I would expect almost any kind of decimal fixed point to outperform decimal floating point, for which I don't really see many redeeming qualities.

Comment: As for overflow, if has that either trap directly or store a trap representation, then one can be assured that if a calculation doesn't overflow one hasn't unexpectedly lost precision.  If one uses a decimal floating-point type for currency and the value gets large enough that the smallest resolvable unit is e.g. ten cents, one wouldn't get any notice that computations are being performed in non-penny-accurate fashion.